# Product of adjacency matrices involving paths.

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Let $A=\textbf{A}_{P_n}$, where $\textbf{A}_{P_n}$ is the adjacency matrix of a path. When we do a graph representation of $A^2-I_n\odot A^2$, we get a graph whose vertex set is defined as $V=\{v_1,v_2,..,v_n\}$ and edge set as $E=\{v_iv_j\;|\;i-j=2\;,\;i>j \}$. I have not been able to prove why this is true.

Edit: ($\odot$ is the Hadamard Product)

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. What exactly is $\odot$ in this context?

Comment: The Hadamard Product

Answer (score 1):

The $(i,j)$ entry of $A^k$ counts the number of length-$k$ walks from $v_i$ to $v_j$.

Therefore $A^2$ counts the length-$2$ walks. For each $i$, there is one length-$2$ walk from $v_i$ to $v_{i \pm 2}$ (whenever that makes sense), and one or two length-$2$ walks from $v_i$ back to itself.

Subtracting $A^2 \odot I$ clears out the diagonal, getting rid of the second type of walk and leaving only the first.

Answer (score 1):

The $i,j$ entry of $A^2$ is given by
$$
[A^2]_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj}.
$$
We therefore see that $v_i v_j \in E$ iff there is a $k$ for which $v_iv_k$ and $v_kv_j$ are edges in the original (path) graph. In other words, we have a non-zero entry iff $|i-j| = |j-k| = 1$. This occurs when $i = j$ and when $|i-j| = 2$. Note that the diagonal entries of $A^2$ are "zeroed out" by the subtraction.